# C# reading value from XML tag by providing nested tags attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read the below value for today's weather warnings from XML file in this link
ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10751.xml

the XML looks like :

```
<forecast>
<area aac="VIC_FA001" description="Victoria" type="region"/>
<area aac="VIC_ME001" description="Melbourne" type="metropolitan" parent-aac="VIC_FA001">
<forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2021-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2021-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2021-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-04-29T14:00:00Z">
<text type="forecast">**Patchy morning fog. Sunny. Light winds.**</text>
<text type="fire_danger">Low-Moderate</text>
<text type="uv_alert">
**Sun protection 10:50am to 1:40pm, UV Index predicted to reach 3 [Moderate]**
</text>
</forecast-period>
<forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2021-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2021-05-01T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2021-04-29T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-04-30T14:00:00Z">
<text type="forecast">
The chance of fog in the early morning. Sunny day. Light winds becoming north to northeasterly 15 to 20 km/h in the late evening.
</text>
</forecast-period>
<forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2021-05-01T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2021-05-02T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2021-04-30T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-05-01T14:00:00Z">
<text type="forecast">Mostly sunny. Winds northerly 25 to 35 km/h.</text>
</forecast-period>
<forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2021-05-02T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2021-05-03T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2021-05-01T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-05-02T14:00:00Z">
<text type="forecast">
Partly cloudy. Slight (20%) chance of a shower. Winds northerly 15 to 25 km/h tending northwest to southwesterly 15 to 20 km/h during the morning then tending southeast to southwesterly during the day.
</text>
</forecast-period>
</forecast-period>
</area>
</forecast>
```

I want to read the info between ** in the above file which can be identified using the below tags and attributes (attribute aac="VIC_ME001" for area and index ="0" for forecast-period) :

```
<area aac="VIC_ME001" >
    <forecast-period index="0" > 
<text type="forecast">**Patchy morning fog. Sunny. Light winds.**</text>
<text type="fire_danger">Low-Moderate</text>
<text type="uv_alert">
**Sun protection 10:50am to 1:40pm, UV Index predicted to reach 3 [Moderate]**
</text>
```

what I tried is the below:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        string url ="ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10751.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("forecast-period"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this examples.There I think you can find:
https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/open-and-read-xml-in-c-examples-using-linq-xmlreader-xmldocu/310

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string URL = @"ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10751.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(URL);
    
    XElement xelem = xdoc.Descendants("area")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("aac").Value.Equals("VIC_ME001"))
        .Elements("forecast-period").Where(x => x.Attribute("index").Value.Equals("0"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
        
    string forecast = xelem.Elements("text")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("type").Value.Equals("forecast")).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("forecast={0}", forecast);
}
```

**Output**

```
forecast=Clear. Light winds.
```

Answer (score 0):

XPATH is a handy syntax to do these type of searches, and you don;t have to worry about null checks if one of the parent elements doesn't exist:

```
xpath = "/forecast/area[@aac='VIC_ME001']/forecast-period[@index='0']/text[@type='forecast']";
textNode = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
if textNode != null
{
    Console.WriteLine("text={0}", textNode.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded schema fro these two locations and used the xsd tool to create c# classes

1. http://www.bom.gov.au/schema/v1.7/amoc.xsd
2. http://www.bom.gov.au/schema/v1.7/product.xsd

   ```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(productType));
            productType product = (productType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
   ```